# How to fix elementary terminal color pallette?

Tags: pantheon-terminal

I am using elementary 5.1.7
When I run `msgcat --color=test` it shows
[image]
Yellow, green and cyan are off. I believe that the elementary terminal colour scheme is a problem because when I ssh from my MacBook to the Elementary desktop, I get normal output.

I can set the palette using dconf. However, I don't know where to get the defaults.

Where can I get those colours?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that this color palette is default in elementary.
I decided to copy palette from iterm2:

```
gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings palette '#000000:#c91b00:#00c200:#c7c400:#0225c7:#c930c7:#00c5c7:#feffff:#676767:#ff6d67:#5ff967:#fefb67:#6871ff:#ff76ff:#5ffdff:#c7c7c7'
```

It gives colors that in the end resemble rainbow much better

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the default palette with `gsettings reset` as follows:

```
gsettings reset io.elementary.terminal.settings palette
```

Comment: The problem is that strange palette *is* the default.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, my bad. I'm glad you were able to get that figured out!